# How to load a drawable on a background thread and draw it on canvas in ReplacementSpan's draw method?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-canvas, android-drawable

I would like to manipulate canvas after loading a drawable from the resources on a background thread. Here is the code (the relevant part):

```
public class Test extends ReplacementSpan {
    @Override
    public void draw(
            final Canvas canvas,
            final CharSequence text,
            final int start,
            final int end,
            final float x,
            final int top,
            final int y,
            final int bottom,
            final Paint paint) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                drawable = context.getResources().getDrawable(resourceId);
                drawable.setBounds(0, 0, size, size);

                canvas.save();
                int transY = bottom - size - paint.getFontMetricsInt().descent;
                canvas.translate(x, transY);
                drawable.draw(canvas);
                canvas.restore();
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

This code leads to a native crash without a stack trace:

```
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xf8 in tid 10735
```

I've noticed that the crash appears when trying to perform any kind of operation on canvas. Putting the code that operates on canvas into `new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {...});` doesn't resolve the issue.

The code works fine if done on the main thread, but it leads to noticeable lags when scrolling.

Is there a way to load the drawable on a background thread and then draw it on canvas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to load the drawable on a background thread and then draw it on canvas?

Yes. Load the drawable outside of `draw()`, on a background thread if you so choose.

Neither `resourceId` nor `size` are parameters to `draw()`. Instead, you are providing those by some other means (constructor, setters, etc.). Obtain and configure your drawable at that point, not in `draw()`. This limits your `draw()` work to only the statements that involve the `Canvas`.

BTW, I'm not 100% certain, but you may need to call `mutate()` on that `Drawable` before calling `setBounds()`, if the same resource is used elsewhere in your app.

Comment: Would it be possible to redraw the span when the drawable is ready then? From what I've tries it's apparently necessary to call setText on the TextView.

Comment: @Buddy: "Would it be possible to redraw the span when the drawable is ready then?" -- I would recommend not using your span until the drawable is ready. IMHO, the responsibility for loading the drawable lies elsewhere, with the span just rendering it.

Comment: I need it for custom Emojis. Preloading them into memory takes a lot of RAM, so I was thinking about a workaround. I agree that the responsibility lies elsewhere but if I load them one by one for a big TextView then I have to call seText every time an emoji is loaded.

Comment: "Preloading them into memory takes a lot of RAM" -- really? You are using them as spans, so they can't be very large in terms of resolution, if they're bitmaps. Ignoring the heap space issue, one possibility would be to put them all in one bitmap, then use `drawBitmap()` on `Canvas` to draw just the emoji you need, pulling in a subset of the bitmap. I don't know where your emoji are coming from, but a custom symbol font might be another option.

Answer (score 0):

try using `runOnMainThread` :

```
public class Test extends ReplacementSpan {
    @Override
    public void draw(
            final Canvas canvas,
            final CharSequence text,
            final int start,
            final int end,
            final float x,
            final int top,
            final int y,
            final int bottom,
            final Paint paint) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                drawable = context.getResources().getDrawable(resourceId);
                drawable.setBounds(0, 0, size, size);
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            canvas.save();
                            int transY = bottom - size - paint.getFontMetricsInt().descent;
                            canvas.translate(x, transY);
                            drawable.draw(canvas);
                            canvas.restore();
                        }
                    });

            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

Comment: `runOnUiThread` is essentially the same as `new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {...});`.